# Need help Centering some Content

Tags: html, alignment

I have two boxes set up and i wanted to put some buttons and text in the middle but when ever I try to add text there it makes the far right box go down one. I want them to stay aligned.

I tried adding another  between the 2 boxes but this did not work. im new at html so im not sure how to format this.

```html
    <!Doctype html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title> Basic Clicker</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="nav_bar">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="GameMainWindow.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="SkillTree.html">SkillTree</a></li>
            <li><a href="Equipment.html">Equipment</a></li>
            <li><a href="Pets.html">Pets</a></li>
            <li><a href="Skills.html" id="onlink">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="Quests.html">Quests</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main_container">
        <p>
            <html>

            <head>
                <title>HTML div</title>
            </head>

            <body>
                <div style="width: 300px; float:left; border: 15px solid green; height:300px; background:white; margin:10px">
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Inventory
                    <br />
                    Bronze: <span id="Bronze">0</span>
                    <br />
                    Silver: <span id="Bronze">0</span>
                    <br />
                    Gold: <span id="Bronze">0</span>
                    <br />
                    Diamond: <span id="Bronze">0</span>
                </div>
                
                <div style="width: 300px;  float:right; border: 15px solid green; height:300px; background:white; margin:10px">
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Skills
                    <br />
                    Strength: Lv <span id="Strengthlv">1</span> <span id="StrengthCexp">0</span> / <span id="StrengthMexp">100</span>
                    <br />
                    Magic: Lv <span id="Magiclv">1</span> <span 
    id="MagicCexp">0</span> / <span id="MagicMexp">100</span>
                        <br />
                        <button onclick="Magicexp()">Click Me!</button>
                        <br />
                    </div>
            
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="Skills.js"></script>  
                    </body>

                </html>

            </p>
        </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

I expect the buttons / words I want to put in the middle of these 2 boxes to not upset the alignment. But my actual output is words and buttons move the far right box down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a flexbox to your code. I hope this was helpful.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Basic Clicker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<style>
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-container>div {
    width: 600px; /*change the max columb width*/
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border: 15px solid green;
    background:white;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main_container">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div style="order: 1">
              <p><b>Inventory</b></p>
              <p>Bronze: <span id="Bronze">0</span></p>
              <p>Silver: <span id="Bronze">0</span></p>
              <p>Gold: <span id="Bronze">0</span></p>
              <p>Diamond: <span id="Bronze">0</span></p>
            </div>
            <div style="order: 3">
              <p><b>Skills</b></p>
              <p>Strength: Lv <span id="Strengthlv">1</span> <span id="StrengthCexp">0</span> / <span id="StrengthMexp">100</span><p/>
              <p>Magic: Lv <span id="Magiclv">1</span> <span 
id="MagicCexp">0</span> / <span id="MagicMexp">100</span></p>
              <button onclick="Magicexp()">Click Me!</button>
            </div>
            <div style="order: 2">
              <h1>content</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- You can add more div's here, if you want -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have any questions, go ahead!

Comment: hey sorry i didnt respond sooner. yesturday power went out and that destroyed my ethernet port on pc. i will try this now to see if i can get it formated the way i want. i basically want a first box with a inventory, middle with a sort of mine and fishing button, and last box is like a leveling skill tree

Comment: does the middle box have to have a green box around it

Comment: Yes, you can change this individually with a class or by id.

Comment: Can i possibly get it edited to do that? been trying im new to html. So 2 side boxes are boxes and middle is like ceptrate from the boxes was going to put a mine and fishing spot in middle

Comment: You can use an iframe with flash player or anything else you want to do that. Just add it to the div with style order 2. Anymore questions just ask :)

Comment: I got it. i just forgot to accept answer thanks http://prntscr.com/nv3lvn

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to approach this problem, just to include a few here in the below code:

You can use bootstrap to implement a grid system, here's the [bootstrap grid system](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) reference.

I have included the grid system in your code. To do that, first is to include bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

What the grid system does is it breaks the width of your row into 12 equal columns, and in the code below, the left box takes 5 columns and the right box takes 5 columns, and the center where you want to add text and stuff will take 2 columns, totaled 12 columns. To do that we add class="col-sm-5" for 5 columns for example, (you can use col-lg-5 etc. you can look it up for more details, basically this has to do with the Responsiveness of your page).

We can also implement [max-width](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp) to limit the maximum width of your center div, and use [overflow wrap](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/) to control the overflow. Look up [CSS overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp) to see what are your options. One of them is to make a scrolling effect if the elements in the center is too big. That way if it overflows and push the right box to the bottom, you can do a scrolling effect so the right box stays where it is.

In the code below `overflow-wrap: break-word;` is used if you were to put text in the middle.

You can also utilize the `position:absolute;` attribute to position your right box in a absolute position, that way it won't be pushed down. See [position](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) for reference.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Basic Clicker</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
          <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="nav_bar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="GameMainWindow.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="SkillTree.html">SkillTree</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Equipment.html">Equipment</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Pets.html">Pets</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Skills.html" id="onlink">Skills</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Quests.html">Quests</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main_container">
        <p>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>HTML div</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div style="float:left; border: 15px solid green; height:300px; background:white; margin:10px" class="col-sm-5">
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Inventory

                                <br />Bronze: 
                                <span id="Bronze">0</span>
                                <br />Silver: 
                                <span id="Bronze">0</span>
                                <br />Gold: 
                                <span id="Bronze">0</span>
                                <br />Diamond: 
                                <span id="Bronze">0</span>
                            </div>
                            <div style="max-width: 30px; overflow-wrap: break-word;" class="col-sm-2">
                                <h1>lkjdlfkjdlkfjdljfdlkjfdlkjfd</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div style="width: 300px;  float:right; border: 15px solid green; height:300px; background:white; margin:10px;" class="col-sm-5">
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Skills

                                <br />Strength: Lv 
                                <span id="Strengthlv">1</span>
                                <span id="StrengthCexp">0</span> / 
                                <span id="StrengthMexp">100</span>
                                <br />Magic: Lv 
                                <span id="Magiclv">1</span>
                                <span 
id="MagicCexp">0</span> / 
                                <span id="MagicMexp">100</span>
                                <br />
                                <button onclick="Magicexp()">Click Me!</button>
                                <br />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="Skills.js"></script>
                </body>
            </html>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ntft3k   i meant to post this but I will try what you suggested

Comment: yea i think my tabs are making this not work correctly dang. sorry i didnt post this at first

Comment: It's normal for the right box to be pushed downwards unless we adjust the center together with the width of the two boxes. The center should have a div, the div width should be specified, the images or things you plan to put should be resized, the padding and the margin of the center div and the things in there should be resized as well, among other things.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ntfxnc So i have this but I cant put another space to move it over a bit more. i want it kind of in the center. when i do another space it goes down a line  .   http://prntscr.com/ntfxxo   here is my code

Comment: You can try flexbox as @Karmakip has suggested, flexbox is a great idea as well